# Is it required to `npm install` every time I change the default Node version used?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I often switch between different Node projects in my `CLI` but I don't know if it is required or not to run `npm install` after changing Node version. For example I have used Node v8 for one project and decided to changed to v10 using `nvm use v10`. Do I have to run `npm install` at that point ?

Comment: Not only `npm install`, it wouldn't hurt to try deleting your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder first before running it. Make sure your `package-lock.json` is backed up or versioned before running it though, in case anything does happen to break and you need to revert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is valid, because `npm install` is time consuming command and downloads lots of data as well.

It is not necessary but dependencies, requirements as well as version of dependencies changes on every node version, so to keep everything up-to-date you need to run `npm install` so that if there is any change then your modules get updated, and to avoid modules error.